# Magento 2 How to Save Data in Two Different Table (Admin Grid Form)

Tags: magento2, admin, uicomponent, backend

In NewAction.php I am saving data in two different tables both have a different model for new contact it's working well, but while editing existing data it's updating first table row and creating a new row in the second table. here in my code "con_id" is the foreign key

```
 class NewAction extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
 {
/**
 * Edit A Contact Page
 *
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page|\Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 */
public function execute()
{
    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_view->renderLayout();

    $contactDatas = $this->getRequest()->getParam('contact');


    if(is_array($contactDatas)) {
        $contact = $this->_objectManager->create(Contact::class);
        $contact->setData($contactDatas)->save();
        $id = $contact->getId();
        $contactt = $this->_objectManager->create(Contactt::class);
        $contactt->setData('con_id', $id);
        $contactt->setData('address', $contactDatas['address']);
        $contactt->setData('zipcode', $contactDatas['zipcode']);
        $contactt->setData('country', $contactDatas['country']);
        $contactt->save();
        if($contact->save()){
             $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved the data.'));
        }else{
             $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Data was not saved.'));
        }
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/index');
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Based on "con_id" on second table load the primary ID (just like you did $id = $contact->getId();) and set in the data and then try.


Also, direct use of ObjectManager is not a good practise in magento2. Please use consturctor based "DI" to create objects of these models. 

public function __construct(Contact $contact, Contactt $contactt){
 $this->contact = $contact;
 $this->contactt = $contatt
}

and then try these objects to save data.

Comment: yes i know but i am learning now so for practice  its save my time, can you tell me how ti load primary ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
namespace My\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Test;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use My\Module\Model\Save as Contact;
use My\Module\Model\Savee as Contactt;
use My\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Save\Add\Collection as listCollectionFactory;


class NewAction extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
/**
 * Edit A Contact Page
 *
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page|\Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)

 */
public function execute()
{
    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_view->renderLayout();

    $contactDatas = $this->getRequest()->getParam('contact');
    if(is_array($contactDatas)) {

        $contact = $this->_objectManager->create(Contact::class);
        $contact->setData($contactDatas)->save();
        $id = $contact->getId();
        $contactt = $this->_objectManager->create(Contactt::class);
        if(isset($contactDatas['id'])){
            $collection = $this->_objectManager->create(listCollectionFactory::class)->load();
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('con_id', ['eq' => $contactDatas['id']]);
            $adddata = $collection->getData()[0];
            if($adddata){
                $contactt->setData('id', $adddata['id']);    
            }
        }
        $contactt->setData('con_id', $id);
        $contactt->setData('address', $contactDatas['address']);
        $contactt->setData('zipcode', $contactDatas['zipcode']);
        $contactt->setData('country', $contactDatas['country']);
        $contactt->save();
        if($contact->save() && $contactt->save()){

             $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved the data.'));
        }else{
             $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Data was not saved.'));
        }
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/index');
    }
}
}
```

By doing this i got solution

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this code

```
class NewAction extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
 {
/**
 * Edit A Contact Page
 *
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page|\Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 */
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();

        $contactDatas = $this->getRequest()->getParam('contact');


        if(is_array($contactDatas)) {
            $contact = $this->_objectManager->create(Contact::class);
            $contact->setData($contactDatas)->save();
            $id = $contact->getId();
            $contactt = $this->_objectManager->create(Contactt::class);
            $contactt->load($id);
            $contactt->setData('address', $contactDatas['address']);
            $contactt->setData('zipcode', $contactDatas['zipcode']);
            $contactt->setData('country', $contactDatas['country']);
            $contactt->save();
            if($contact->save()){
                 $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved the data.'));
            }else{
                 $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Data was not saved.'));
            }
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/index');
        }
    }
}
```

hope it solves your problem

Comment: please let me know if it works or require modification

Comment: Its creating new row in second table, and also con_id value is set for new contact is 0

Comment: hello can you help me????

Comment: you have the same problem?

Comment: yes, can you tell me how to add filter for second table

Comment: which filter you want to add explain me in detail

Comment: i want to get id based on con_id in second table

Comment: $ots = $contactt->addFieldToFilter('con_id', array('eq' => $contactDatas['id']));
i am trying this but its generate error

Comment: did you print $contactDatas['id']?

Comment: yes, i am getting value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97712/discussion-between-asq-and-hardik-radadiya).